# How to build war using Jenkins from a Dynamic Web Project without using Gradle or Maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins

I want to create a war file using Jenkins from a Dynamic web project where my jars are in classpath and lib folder. I tried using maven and gradle, it is working good. But I want to convert a dynamic web project into war without maven or gradle using Jenkins. I searched on many websites all are suggesting to use maven or gradle. How to make Jenkins understand that required jars are in classpath file or lib folder to build war? Please suggest me a way to build war without maven or gradle.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seeking answer for the same. If found please provide solution.